# ReferenceError: bot is not defined

Tags: discord

This is something with the const or var. I think that it won't work unless I recode it. Here is my problem:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
^

ReferenceError: bot is not defined
    at C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\discord bot\app.js:7:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord');
const bot = new Discord.Bot();
const fs = require('fs')
const commandsList = fs.readFileSync('Storage/commands.txt','utf8');
});

bot.on('ready', () => {
  // This event will run if the bot starts, and logs in, successfully.
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels.`);
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
     message.channel.send('pong');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!apply') {
     message.channel.send('GOGLE STUFF');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!server') {
     message.channel.send('LA');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!do you know dae wae') {
     message.channel.send('Yes I know dae wae brother');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'do you have a bot?') {
     message.channel.send('no');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'who is the owner') {
     message.channel.send('FantasmicNerd, duh');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'can i be staff' || message.content === 'can I be staff?' || message.content === 'can i be staff?') {
     message.channel.send('Application - lalalalalala');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'somebody touch my spaghet') {
     message.channel.send('SOMEBODY TOUCH YOUR SPAGHET!');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'so how about that airline food') {
     message.channel.send('HAAHAHAHHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAAHAHAHHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHAHA');
   }
});

bot.on('ready',() => {
    console.log('Bot Launched...')

    bot.user.setStatus('Online')

    bot.user.setActivity('on The Magical')
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '?help' || message.content === '?Help') {
     message.channel.send('I have messaged you the commands and prefix.');
   }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '?help' || message.content === '?Help') {
     message.author.sendMessage(commandsList);
   }
});

bot.on('ready', function() {
    bot.user.setUsername("The Magical");

// THIS  MUST  BE  THIS  WAY
bot.login('NDA0NjYzNzIwNDQzMzc5NzEy.DUapFw.zjDvPkG4QxZJ1rdxDYaPZEaVpiM');
```

I have looked all over for answers but nothing seems to work. I end up with this in `cmd` prompt when I try to run it

Comment: Can you show the console output?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Where you're requiring the library you need to change it to `discord.js` to get access to the library.
Also the library does not expose a class called "Bot" so you need change that to ["Client"](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

I'm guessing the `)};` on line 5 is supposed to be closing the `ready` event on line 88.
But I suggest you just stick with one ready event, so put the status and activity methods in the first ready event and remove the other ones. Also, if you've set your bot username to what you want I would remove that method, or put a check to see if the username is already set to what you want, and if it is then don't change it.

Same with all the `message` events as the ready ones, stick to one `message` event and just chain all the if statements in that one. Example:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
    else if (message.content === '!apply') {
        message.channel.send('GOGLE STUFF');
    }
    ...
});
```

Also you need to remember what you define your variables as. In the first `ready` event you use `client.users` instead of what you have defined, which is `bot`.

Answer (score 1):

According to discord.js API document, there is no Bot class.
Maybe what you need is

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

I suggest you check the document and example for your application.